# SceneBuilder failed to launch says "No main class specified"

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder

I installed SceneBuilder 8.5.0, now after installing the SceneBuilder for the first time, it works properly, but next time that I would want to open it, it gives an error `No main class specified` after that it says `failed to launch JVM`

This keeps making me to uninstall the previous one and installing a new one each time I want to use it. Anyone knows what might be causing this?

I have tried launching it with the executable jar file called `dist.jar` inside the the `app` folder in the installation directory, it launched properly but when i tried specifying the executable jar file as the SceneBuilder executable path in eclipse IDE, I get this error each time I want to open an `fxml` file with SceneBuilder.

`Failed to launch SceneBuilder. The error message was: Cannot run program "C:\SceneBuilder\app\dist.jar": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application`

This means I must specify the `.exe` executable file which doesn't work.

Any help help or clue would be appreciated.

Comment: What JDK version do you use? Which Windows version? Did you install the SceneBuilder or are you using the jar only?

Comment: @Mosch I am using JDK 1.8, like i said in the question,  I installed the scenebuilder, which i downloaded from [here](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/). I am using windows 7 64bit

Comment: Okay so which version of SceneBuilder have you installed? You could try the jar executable the 64bit or 32bit versions of SceneBuilder 8.5.0.  11.0.0 wont work with JDK 1.8. do you have the JDK 32bit or 64bit on your system?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

> CTRL + ALT + S, click to JavaFx
>
> Then look for SceneBuilder.exe in **C:\ProgramFiles\SceneBuilder**

I had the same problem. When I upgraded the scene builder from 8 to 11, I unconsciously recorded another path. The problem was fixed when I changed the path with **C:\ProgramFiles\SceneBuilder\SceneBuilder.exe** I mean maybe you have more than 1 scene builder folder like me.